# Java: Trying to print an object of a class, one instance variable is price, need to format it as such (without printf somehow??)

Tags: java, format

```
public Foo(String name, double price)  
    {  
        this.name = name; 
        this.price = price;  
    }     
    // Overrride toString() for use of System.out.print() with Foo objects  
    public String toString()  
    {  
        return "Name: " + name + "\nPrice: $" + price + "\n";  
    }
```

System.out.println(anyFoo); will only present a price in proper format if its a double with two digits after the decimal. How do I format this like with printf if I'm using a return statement?

Thanks!

Comment: if iam not wrong, there is no function called printf in java

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.format(String format, Object ... args)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format`. Read this info: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (remember to add `import java.text.*;`)

```
//... bla bla..
DecimalFormat myDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
return "Name: " + name + "\nPrice: $" + myDecimalFormat .format(price)+ "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DecimalFormat as in;

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat( "#,###,###,##0.00" );
double d = 123.456789;
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```